# How to know when click on the map there is already a circle created and show alert to delete and edit that circle in MAPKIT?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

We have created a circle using long pressed gesture on the map.

Now when I again click on the same position the new circle is created then how we know about that the circle is already created in that location.

So we prompt the alert to edit or delete the old circle instead of creating a new circle on the same radius /location.

```
//Make circle on map
 MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:oomLocation radius:1000];
[self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the all overlays that have been added on mapView using following code.

```
self.mapView.overlays
```

It will return  an array containing all overlays. You can then check for  existence of any prior overlay.